# Ghost.py - what does this stack trace mean?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ghost.py

How do I go about debugging this stack trace?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 73, in execInThread
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\netref.py", line 196, in __call__
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\netref.py", line 71, in syncreq
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\protocol.py", line 431, in sync_request
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\protocol.py", line 379, in serve
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\protocol.py", line 337, in _recv
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\channel.py", line 50, in recv
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\stream.py", line 166, in read
EOFError: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

The stack trace does not refer to a line in my code, which is too long to reproduce here. However, the key component other than the standard python library is [Ghost.py](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This means the server closed the connection unexpectedly, usually because it crashed for some reason. In this case, it looks like the client is pyscripter and the server is a subprocess running your app, and it sounds like the subprocess crashed so hard that it did not gracefully close the connection or send back a meaningful traceback. So, either there is a bug in pyscripter or a bug in your code. My advice is to run your app without the IDE and see if you can reproduce the issue and get a meaningful traceback.

Comment: I've tried running from the command line, but unfortunately it crashes without leaving a traceback. In fact it crashes most of the time in the IDE without a traceback, but every now any then I get what was posted.

Comment: @user1379351 Unfortunately that sounds like a hard crash, i.e. some C extension or even python itself segfaulted. If you're up to the task, you can attempt to debug the issue with Visual Studio or WinDbg, but if you're not familiar with C or assembly it's going to be tough.